How to control a spark streaming job with airflow
1.I have a spark streaming job that reads kafka, transforms and saves data to files

The files then need to be delivered to gcs (I would save them directly with spark, but I can't use grpc based connectors in my environment)

After delivering the files, I need to send a flag through GCP pubsub .


Below topics discuss some parts of my problem:

Using airflow to run spark streaming jobs?
Can airflow be used to run a never ending task?

So far the best idea I have is having 2 dags

One having an infinite task, with spark submit and streaming job inside it. This spark job would keep saving the files to some staging folder. I would be able to kill or restart the stream with it, and also access logs in the webUI.
Another dag that has a sensor looking at the folder every X minutes and shipping files to the bucket + sending a pubsub flag. It would be mini batches, and the dag would start and end every couple minutes.

These two dags would be independent of each other.
Is there any better/nicer way to control my flow?
Thanks a lot
